# Get tests to be executed in [SetUpFixture] while running via nunit3-console.exe

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm using NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.8.0 to run NUnit 3.10.1 tests.

The problem is: if there is specific tests in run filter, I should properly configure my SUT. It is quite painful process, so I would like to do it only if some specific test should be ran.

Is any way to receive list of tests to be ran by console runner, ideally in SetUpFixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **any** tests in the same namespace (or descendants) as the `SetUpFixture` are selected, the the `SetUpFixture` will be run. If none are selected, then it will not be run.

Since this is how `SetUpFixtures` work, you should organize your tests so that only those that need this configuration step are in the namespaces covered by the `SetUpFixture`.

In my experience working with teams, I have found that they are sometimes hampered by standards (imposed or self-chosen) that require the test namespaces to conform to a particular design. This is a bad idea when using a system like NUnit that depends on the namespace structure to control how tests are executed.

Comment: I thought about this, but how about parallel tests execution? SUT configuration in `SetUpFixture` for specific tests will begin while tests in other `SetUpFixture` start to execute and they will fail.

Comment: Parallelism is another matter. You should first get your tests to work correctly in a namespace structure that allows the SetUpFixture for a group of TestFixxtures to perform correctly. Once that is done, you can use attributes to define which ones are able to run in parallel and which ones are not.